# Update a table column with data from another table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-update

I've searched everywhere but I can't seem to make it work or understand why the join is behaving like this and right now I am not able to ask anyone so just trying my luck here. So here's the issue:

**tblOldAccess**

```
User      Srv    Perm    LogDtTm
------------------------------------------------
TestNm1   Srv1   Perm1   2016-09-20 00:00:00.000
TestNm1   Srv2   Perm2   2016-05-30 00:00:00.000
TestNm1   Srv1   Perm3   2016-05-30 00:00:00.000
```

**tblNewAccess**

```
User      Srv    Perm    LogDtTm
------------------------------------------------
TestNm1   Srv1   Perm1   2016-11-20 00:00:00.000
TestNm1   Srv2   Perm2   2016-12-30 00:00:00.000
TestNm1   Srv1   Perm4   2017-02-01 21:50:32.197
```

If there are same User, Srv, and Perm between the 2 tables, I wanted to update the **tblOldAccess** tabke with the current LogDtTm from **tblNewAccess** like this

**Desired result** - 
**tblOldAccess**

```
   User      Srv    Perm    LogDtTm
    ------------------------------------------------
    TestNm1   Srv1   Perm1   2016-11-20 00:00:00.000
    TestNm1   Srv2   Perm2   2016-12-30 00:00:00.000
    TestNm1   Srv1   Perm3   2016-05-30 00:00:00.000
```

I am able to get the rows which have the same info for User, Srv, Perm
through the ***INTERSECT*** command however I am unable to join them properly so as to get something like this:

```
UPDATE [tblOldAccess]
    SET [LogDtTm] = [tmp].[LogDtTm]
FROM tblOldAccessas tmp
 JOIN (
    SELECT [user], Srv, [Perm] from [tblNewAccess]
    INTERSECT
    SELECT [user], Srv, [Perm] from [tblOldAccess]
) as drv
ON tmp.[User] = drv.[User]
WHERE tmp.[User] = drv.[User]
AND tmp.[Srv] = drv.[Srv]
```

I have tried multiple join condition and even multiple where condition to only update those 2 rows which correspond to ones that needs update in their LogDtTm **column** in the **tblOldAccess** table. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't add any primary key or ID since these columns can actually have same values(with different combinations). Thus i needed to check per row.

Comment: Have you looked into [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)? I believe you could get your desired result this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
UPDATE old
SET old.[LogDtTm] = new.[LogDtTm]
FROM tblOldAccess old
INNER JOIN tblNewAccess new ON old.[User] = new.[User] AND 
                               old.[Srv] = new.[Srv] AND 
                               old.[Perm] = new.[Perm]
```

Note : First Take backup of your data

Comment: (0 row(s) affected) on my end buddy. also I ran 
`SELECT * FROM tblOldAccess old
INNER JOIN tblNewAccess new ON old.[User] = new.[User] AND 
                               old.[Srv] = new.[Srv] AND 
                               old.[Perm] = new.[Perm]`

and it gave me an empty table

Comment: Hmm this seems to be data issue. there may be posibility to not find any match as per our join condition.

Comment: that's what I'm also thinking since I've tried this approach earlier and it also returned 0 rows. I will check the data on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Check the collation level, since you are joining on string datatypes. May be this will help you out.

Comment: Hi I already checked all the collations(DB & columns) and they all check out so this isn't an issue with collation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that helped! I've finally manage to track down the issue and sadly(frustratingly) its just a null value in some rows in the entire table which prevented the JOIN to function properly. Here's some [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190409(v=sql.105).aspx).
I've created a work around this by using `COALESCE` and it now works perfectly! Thanks everyone! If anyone was wondering here's my current syntax:

```
UPDATE old
    SET old.[LogDtTm] = new.[LogDtTm]
FROM [tblOldAccess] as old
INNER JOIN [tbNewAccess] new 
    ON  COALESCE(old.[User],'noValue') = COALESCE(new.[User],'noValue')
    AND  COALESCE(old.[Srv],'noValue') = COALESCE(new.[Srv],'noValue')
    AND COALESCE(old.[Perm],'noValue') = COALESCE(new.[Perm],'noValue')
```